# How to download linked text - Selenium C#

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath, href

I am trying to create an automation for downloading files from lined text.
Unfortunatly I can't get it to work. I am new to selenium.

Here is an HTML site code:

#### Ttnc-18p - 17.34 GB

```
<table class="table table-stripped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Größe</th>
            <th>DL</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
                    <tr>
            <td><a href="/get/vobqwunyrrxl2oo5">Ttnc-18p.part01.rar</a>
            </td><td>500.00 MB</td>
            <td><a href="/get/vobqwunyrrxl2oo5"><img width="16" height="16" src="//filer.net/media/images/ico_arrow_down.png?2018" alt="DL"></a>
        </td></tr>
                    <tr>
            <td><a href="/get/rgpwrydtby6s1zdh">Ttnc-18p.part01.rev</a>
            </td><td>500.00 MB</td>
            <td><a href="/get/rgpwrydtby6s1zdh"><img width="16" height="16" src="//filer.net/media/images/ico_arrow_down.png?2018" alt="DL"></a>
        </td></tr>
                    <tr>
            <td><a href="/get/qjfyfyusx9pbycrg">Ttnc-18p.part02.rar</a>
            </td><td>500.00 MB</td>
            <td><a href="/get/qjfyfyusx9pbycrg"><img width="16" height="16" src="//filer.net/media/images/ico_arrow_down.png?2018" alt="DL"></a>
        </td></tr>
                    <tr>
            <td><a href="/get/pydwswtrhoqenolb">Ttnc-18p.part03.rar</a>
            </td><td>500.00 MB</td>
            <td><a href="/get/pydwswtrhoqenolb"><img width="16" height="16" src="//filer.net/media/images/ico_arrow_down.png?2018" alt="DL"></a>
        </td></tr>
```

I want it to download the link from: Ttnc-18p.part01.rar, Ttnc-18p.part02.rar, Ttnc-18p.part03.rar and so on...
I tried this:

```
ChromeDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("/table[contains(@class,'table table-stripped')]/tbody/tr/td/a[contains(text(),'" + "Ttnc-18p.part01.rar" + "')]")).Click();
```

It doesn't work and I can't figure out what to do. Any thing else fails.

The second thing I am trying to is that the code will generate an array of links that it need to download so I can feed the code different website that have differend number of linkes.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below, but you would likely want to break the these in to separate methods for reusability:

```
public IEnumerable<string> DownloadLinks(string url)
{
    // for storing each href value as it is retrieved from the links
    var listOfLinks = new List<string>();

    // start your instance of ChromeDriver
    var driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    // Navigate to the url you passed in
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

    // Get a collection of all anchor ("a") tags. 
    var anchorTags= driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));

    // Now for each anchor tag...
    foreach(var link in anchorTags)
    {
        // ...retrieve the value of its 'href' attribute (i.e. your link)...
        var l = link.GetAttribute("href");
        
        // ...add the link path to your listOfLinks
        // and append your url to the href since the href is only a partial 
        // ( /get/vobqwunyrrxl2oo5 becomes https://yourwebsite.com/get/vobqwunyrrxl2oo5)
        listOfLinks.Add(url + l);
        
        // now click your link to simulate clicking the link and downloading the file
        link.Click();
    }

    // and finally return your list of links
    return listOfLinks;

}
```

Comment: Hey thank you but two things: 1. .Dump() is in error when I am trying to use it. 2. what is the veriable "anchorTags" in the foreach because it is also in red in my code. @Stemado

Comment: .Dump() is an extension for LINQPad and anchorTags was what I renamed hyperlinks just without actually changing the variable. The code is updated now